# Reducing spaces in tikz macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want this:

[image]

I got this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% overhead arrow 
\newcommand{\arrowlefto}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (base) {#1};
    \node (dir) [right=0.1cm of base] {$^{#2}$};
    \draw[->] (dir.north) .. controls ++(0,.25) and ++(0,.25) .. (base.north);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    There is a mismatch in combination of the numbers. We have three different numbers: all of them are set in sequence except the leftmost digit, other positions have only one digit each. So the rest of digits will be forwarded in their preceding positions. Example: 36 $^85$ $^{31}9$ Or 36 \arrowlefto{6}{8}\arrowlefto{5}{31}9 
\end{document}
```

How?

**Concern Only**: a lot of spaces, nice arrow, baseline of numbers (All are highlighted), not the font or size

Comment: you are adding a space before every tikzpicture, use `newcommand{\arrowlefto}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}` with no space after the `{`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No significant changes

Comment: well it will remove one inter-word space before each arrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what I'd do:

1. Following David Carlisle's comment, remove the space after `\newcommand{\arrowlefto}[2]{`.
2. Fix the `tikzpicture` baseline w.r.t. the `base` node.
3. Reduce the arrow size and/or add space between lines.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage    {amsmath}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% to reduce the arrow head

% overhead arrow 
\newcommand{\arrowlefto}[2]{% <-- no need for a space here
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(base.south)]% <-- fixing the baseline
    \node[inner sep=0] (base) {#1};
    \node[inner sep=0] (dir)  [right=0.1cm of base] {$^{#2}$};
    \draw[-{Latex[length=1mm]}] ([yshift=0.5ex]dir.north) to[out=150,in=30] ([yshift=0.5ex]base.north);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}% we need a little more space between the lines because the arrows

\begin{document}
    There is a mismatch in combination of the numbers. We have three different numbers: all of them are set in sequence except the leftmost digit, other positions have only one digit each. So the rest of digits will be forwarded in their preceding positions. Example: 36 $^85$ $^{31}9$ Or 36 \arrowlefto{6}{8}\arrowlefto{5}{31}9 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: screenshot]

The `base` keyword is a native option of `Tikz`, so I renamed it `X` (*see section 17.5.1 Positioning Nodes Using Anchors*).
To connect 2 nodes, there is an operation called `edge` (*see 17.12 Connecting Nodes: Using the Edge Operation*)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,bending}

% overhead arrow 
\newcommand{\arrowlefto}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[% definition of styles
    every node/.style={inner ysep=2pt,inner xsep=0pt},
    every edge/.style={bend right=50,->,draw},
    >={Latex[length=1.5pt 2]},
    baseline=(X.base)]% end definition of style
    \node (X) {#1};
    \node (dir) [right=1ex of X] {$^{#2}$}  edge   (X.north);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    There is a mismatch in combination of the numbers. We have three different numbers: all of them are set in sequence except the leftmost digit, other positions have only one digit each. So the rest of digits will be forwarded in their preceding positions. Example: 36 $^85$ $^{31}9$ Or 36 \arrowlefto{6}{8}\arrowlefto{5}{31}9 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution.☺️